# Calling variables from overloaded constructors

Tags: java, variables, constructor, overloading, constructor-overloading

I'm having an issue getting the variables in the constructors to show up in my output in my main method. I can get the program to work just using methods, however, the problem arises when using constructors. Any help or tip in the right direction would be great!

```
public class Time {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TimeCalculations time1 = new TimeCalculations();
        System.out.println(time1.getCurrentTime());
        System.out.println(time1.getElaspedTime());

    public static long input() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a time");
        return TimeCalculations.elaspedTime = input.nextLong();}

class TimeCalculations {
    public long currentTime;
    public static long elaspedTime;


public TimeCalculations() {

    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
    }

    public TimeCalculations(long currentTime, long elaspedTime) {
        elaspedTime = currentTime -Time.input();
    }

    public long getCurrentTime() {
    return this.currentTime;
    }

public long getElaspedTime() {      
    return TimeCalculations.elaspedTime;
    }
```

Comment: What exact problem are you having?

Comment: I can get my currentTime variable (time in milliseconds) to show up in my output, but not the elaspedTime variable. In my second constructor I have tried even just setting elaspedTime to a given value with still no return to my output. I did not include my input method to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry! but I didn't get this!  "***however, the problem arises when using constructors***" 
Can you please give some more details!
 Thanks!
Thanks! for your details.
just call the input method in **public static void main** at first line

```
import java.util.*;
public class Time{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input();
    TimeCalculations time1 = new TimeCalculations();
    System.out.println(time1.getCurrentTime());
    System.out.println(time1.getElaspedTime());
}
 public static long input() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a time");
    return TimeCalculations.elaspedTime = input.nextLong();}

}

class TimeCalculations {
public long currentTime;
public static long elaspedTime;


public TimeCalculations() {
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
}

public long getCurrentTime(){
    return this.currentTime;
}

public long getElaspedTime() {      
    return TimeCalculations.elaspedTime;
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using elapsedTime as a static variable?

Comment: Yes. I made the same program but with regular methods with a return statement. From there, I was able to get each value into my output. When I changed the methods into constructors, I cannot pass the values to the other class. Does that help at all?

Comment: When I change it to a non-static, I get an compile error "cannot make static reference to a non-static field." in my second constructor.

Comment: can you post Time.input here? what are you doing it in the input method?

Comment: I couldn't format it right in the comment box so I added it in my main code.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! It is, but I'm still having issues getting the user inputted time to calculate. All it does is output the inputted time.

Answer (score 0):

In your second constructor, you are essentially not doing anything.  Since you are using the same variable names as parameters, your global variables `elaspedTime` and `currentTime` are hidden.  Change it to the following:  (add the `this.`)

```
public TimeCalculations(long currentTime, long elaspedTime) {
    this.elaspedTime = currentTime -Time.input();
}
```

Secondly, it doesn't make sense what you are doing in this constructor.  In this case, passing currentTime and elapsedTime as constructor params means you should just set them to the globals like:

```
public TimeCalculations(long currentTime, long elaspedTime) {
    this.elaspedTime = elapseTime;
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
}
```

In your first constructor, you are just setting currentTime twice.  Change to something like:

```
public TimeCalculations() {
    // since there is no local var named currentTime, you don't need
    // to put this.
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```